# Problem with 'Cannot assign' error in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have something like this in my template.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
     <select name='section'>
      {% for item in all_sections %}
              <option>{{ item.SectionName }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
     </select>
</form>
```

and in my view.py page:

```
obj=models.Section.objects.all()
context={
    'all_sections':obj,
}
return render(request,'matab/add-service.html',context)
```

but i get this is error while saving data:

> Cannot assign "'{item}'": "Services.Section" must be a "Section" instance.

also my models.py is like this:

```
class Section(models.Model):
SectionName=models.CharField(max_length=50)
SectionId=models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Services(models.Model):
Section=models.OneToOneField(
    Section,
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
)
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: Why are you not using django forms?

Comment: @IainShelvington they asked me to not working with forms

Comment: That's just making a lot more work for yourself... options should have a value `<option value="{{ item.id }}">`

Comment: But seriously, just use a ModelForm and it will handle most of the input rendering and input cleaning/conversion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Services.Section` is a `OneToOneField`, so you need to assign `Section` instance, not its name.

Depending on your code, it might work if you set the option value to the pk.

```
 <select name='section'>
  {% for item in all_sections %}
          <option value="{{ item.pk }}">{{ item.SectionName }}</option>
  {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

As Iain suggests in the comments, it would be better to change your views to use Django forms instead of manually render `select` inputs.